# HTTP Basic Auth not bring up password prompt in <Directory> but in <Location> in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vhosts, apache2.4

Apache Version: 2.4.17

vhost.config:

```
Listen 1449

<VirtualHost *:1449>

    DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php

    ServerName 200.000.000.00:1449

    ServerAdmin myname

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:5000/custom/$1 

    DocumentRoot /custom

    <Directory /custom>

        Options -Indexes -Includes

        AllowOverride None

        Allow from All

        AuthBasicProvider file

        AuthName "Restricted Area" 

        AuthType Basic 

        AuthUserFile "/passward/.main" 

        Require valid-user

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The only general directory tag in http.config:

```
<Directory />

    <LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
         deny from all
   </LimitExcept>

    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied

</Directory>
```

I have another vhost with the exact same setting and password and it is working. But I have no idea why it is not working in this specific virtual host in port `1449`. When I browse at `200.000.000.00:1449/custom/some.php`, it doesn't bring up a dialog asking for the password. It just goes straight to the page. I have to use `<Location>` tags to bring up a password prompt, but I have read that it isn't safer than `<Directory>`. No error log at all. Completely mysterious to me.

Can anyone figure out what is wrong with the setting?

Updated:

Working:

```
<Location />

   AuthType Basic 

   .....

</Location>
```

Not Working:

```
<Directory />

      AuthType Basic 

      .....

</Directory>
```

Not Working:

```
<Files "some.php">

       AuthType Basic 

       .....

</Files>
```

The File Path:

```
  /custom/some.php 0644
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ProxyPass/ProxyPassmatch`, the request is never mapped to any location on disk, so you can't use `<Directory>` sections.

There is an alternate form of FCGI that uses `SetHandler` instead of `ProxyPass/ProxyPassmatch` (it's in the manual) that delays execution and allows the normal mapping to disk to happen.  Give that a try if you need it.